# How to access variable calculated in other js file?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, variables, scope

Just a simple example make it clear:
In this example how can I use the calculated machineLength in angularApp.js?
For now, it output an empty object, not the calculated in the angularApp.js.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="...">...</script>
    <script>
      let machineLength={};
    </script>
    <script src="angularApp.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...


    <script>
      console.log(machineLength);
      // here is a lot of code use machineLength to render scene of models with three.js
      //the machineLength is the render region width, height. length
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

angularApp.js:

```
  let sliceApp = angular.module('sliceConfig', []);
  sliceApp.
    .controller('sliceConfigController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)
    {
        $http.get("http://xxxxx/getSliceConfig")
          .success(function(response)
          {
            $scope.config = [];
            $scope.config.machine_width = machineLength.x = parseFloat(response.config.machine_width);
            ...
          }
    }]);
```

Any helps will be appreciated!

Comment: angular.value might help

Comment: @A.J will you give more info, how to use angular.value? Thanks

Comment: I don't have access to laptop at the moment I will post an example after an hour maybe. Thanks (using mobile to communicate at the moment) ;)

Comment: Thank you in advance. I'm waiting for you info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `angularApp.js` uses an asynchronous ajax call, and the script in your main page prints `machineLength` before the response arrives.

One solution would be for your angularApp script to inform the script in your main page when the response arrives. In angularApp.js:

```
...
.success(function(response) {
        $scope.config = [];
        $scope.config.machine_width = machineLength.x = parseFloat(response.config.machine_width);
        angularFinishedJob(); // call the script in the main page when job is done
...
```

Main page:

```
<script>
  console.log(machineLength); // empty object, because angular job didn't finish

  function angularFinishedJob(){  // called from angularApp.js
      console.log(machineLength); // calculated object
      // add code which uses machineLength
  }
</script>
```

*Note: I think this would be the easiest method to implement if you have access to modifying `angularApp.js`. If not, others solutions exist*

Comment: Yeah, this works for the console.log(machineLength). But actually here is a lot of code render a scene, that use the machineLength. How can I block the render befor machineLength assigned?

Comment: Add that code in `angularFinishedJob()`, or call the function which is rendering from `angularFinishedJob()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Providers value recipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.value('m_width', '100'); //some init value

myApp.controller('DemoController', ['m_width', function DemoController(m_width) {

$http.get("http://xxxxx/getSliceConfig")
      .success(function(response)
      {
        $scope.config = [];
        var x = //something from response;
        $scope.$emit('eventName', { width: x });
        ...
      }

}]);

myApp.controller('otherController', ['m_width', function otherController(m_width) {

   $scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) {
    $scope.message = args.width;
    console.log($scope.message);
   });

   $scope.width = m_width;

}]);
```

Comment: if use the init value in the follow render, the machineLength is the render region width, height. length. The scene will render a initial scene with the init value, then when the $http.get returns I've to rerender the scene.

Comment: Well, this was to answer your question, when you wanted to access a variable across controllers. But your use case is different. For your requirements, I would rather use $emit and $on watch expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your time and info. Will you show more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Inject $window and use that:

```
  let sliceApp = angular.module('sliceConfig', []);
  sliceApp.
    .controller('sliceConfigController', function($window, $scope, $http)
    {
        $http.get("http://xxxxx/getSliceConfig")
          .success(function(response)
          {
            $scope.config = [];
            //$scope.config.machine_width = machineLength.x = parseFloat(response.config.machine_width);
            $scope.config.machine_width = $window.machineLength.x = parseFloat(response.config.machine_width);
            ...
          }
    });
```

I don't recommend using either the global object or `$rootScope` for storing values but it will work.

Instead, I recommend using a value provider:

```
  let sliceApp = angular.module('sliceConfig', []);

  sliceApp.value("machineLength", {});
  sliceApp.
    .controller('sliceConfigController', function(machineLength, $scope, $http)
    {
        $http.get("http://xxxxx/getSliceConfig")
          .success(function(response)
          {
            $scope.config = [];
            $scope.config.machine_width = machineLength.x = parseFloat(response.config.machine_width);
            ...
          }
    });
```